# Use The New Sheqel sign on mac

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I have a macbook pro (15 inch mid 2015 with macOS High Sierra) with Hebrew keyboard (the keyboard has this https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/hebrew_notebook.png layout, this is European layout with Hebrew keys on it).

On the '7' key there are the '&' and the '₪' sings. The '&' sign can be triggered by the standard `shift-7` shortcut, but I don't have any idea for how to use the '₪' sign (its pretty useful in Hebrew). I haven't found any solution (not online or in the keyboard settings), does anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in High Sierra and using the Apple "Hebrew" or "Hebrew qwerty" input source, you should get ₪ via Shift-7.  For & you have to do caps lock shift 7.

If you are using the "Hebrew PC" layout, ₪ will be Option 4 (and Shift 7 will give you &).

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources will let you add multiple international keyboard configurations, and both Hebrew and Hebrew (QWERTY) map the ₪ symbol to shift-7. In that preference pane, you can also add the Input menu to your menu bar, which will show you what keyboard input is active with a little flag icon, and it will let you switch between them easily.

To get the ₪ sign regardless of what keyboard input is selected, you could go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Text and add a text replacement shortcut like ";sheq" or ";שקל" and paste the ₪ character in. Then every time you type that string (the appended ; will prevent you from ever typing it unintentionally), the system will auto-suggest ₪ to replace it.